# When is a loop in a linked list useful?

Tags: algorithm

Determining whether a singly-linked list has a loop is a common interview question. But why would a linked list exist with a loop? When would a linked list with a loop be useful?

Comment: Check out this wiki article about it - [Circularly linked vs linearly linked](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Circularly_linked_vs._linearly_linked)

Comment: Example: You're implementing a board game where players play by turns. Each player node points to the next player.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Circularly linked lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Circularly_linked_list) can be useful if you want to iterate through the entire list starting from a random iterator or inserting in any position. They simplify the algorithms for those operations as you don't have to account for the beginning or end of the list.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter then, which of the elements you pass to the function as a parameter, for example. When using sentinel pattern, you will iterate over each elements all the same.

Answer (score 0):

Apache uses circularly linked lists to store all its filters.

For some reason they gave it a fancy marketing name *(["Bucket Brigades"](http://www.apachetutor.org/dev/brigades))* and call it *"a major innovation"* - lol.

Answer (score 0):

To use circularly linked lists, you can think about structures that are circular by nature. Such as pool of buffers that are used and released in FIFO order, or a set of processes that should be time-shared in round-robin order, or saving the nodes coordinates of a polygon in their specific order.

Answer (score 0):

Many answers given here consider *Completely looped* Linked List.

The interview question is a bit different. We've to detect loop (can be *partial*) somewhere in the link

Eg: (sorry for poor graphics)

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5

          ^         v

          7 <-----  6
```

Answer to how it can happen: Link corruption. 
a) People trying to crack in through UGC (User Generated Content). Bad data can come up.
b) Design flaws in early stages.

This loop detection is also part of testing we do on LinkedLists to look for suspected bugs.

You've not asked for solutions, but I'll put a few here in brief:

1. Keep pushing nodes to List (Arraylist in java). The time you find duplicate: Loop detected
2. Turtle & Hare approach. Turtle jumps one node at a time. Rabbit, two at a time. They meet if it's a loop
3. store boolean flag *visited* as you traverse. Any encounter of *true* is loop.